# How to get the connection string value from hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using Fluent NHibernate and need to get my Connection String from the **connection.connection_string** property on **hibernate.cfg.xml** file to create my Session Factory:

```
private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory {
   get {
      return = Fluently.Configure()
         .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("MyConnStr")))
         .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<FooMap>())
         .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.Properties.Add("hbm2ddl.keywords", "none"))
         .BuildSessionFactory();
   }
}
```

I want to replace MyConnStr (that is in my web.config file) "**c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("MyConnStr")**" for the connection string from the **hibernate.cfg.xml** file.

I've tried use NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString, but it didn't work.

How can I get this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure();
string conString = cfg.Configuration.GetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString);
```

Comment: I had to edit the second line to be: `string conString = cfg.GetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString)`

Answer (score 4):

**Updated for your updated question**

```
public static string ConnectionString
{
  get
  {
    NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
    return cfg.GetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to get this on my SessionFactory getter. I want the NHibernate connection string to create my SessionFactory. I'm using Fluent NHibernate.

Comment: @MCardinale - The factory should be using this connection string natively, you need to change it or...?

Comment: I have edited my question, adding my SessionFactory's code. I want use the connection string from NHibernate instead of Web.config or a hard coded string because this Factory is on a Class Library to reuse in other projects. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MCardinale - Updated the answer, you can use this as a property on whatever you like to fetch the string.

Comment: if you put this as-is it is going to rebuild the configuration each and everytime you try to get the ConnectionString

Comment: @Jaguar - We cached this in a central spot before moving away, but you're right without that not a great idea...been a while since we moved away from nHibernate.

Comment: Strange but this returns null for me.I'm using it in a test to open a non-NH connection, and detect if `SchemaExport` has created a table. The table is created, so NH had the correct connection string at some point.